# Flutter throw error while debugging - Compiler message: lib/views/signUp.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html' import 'dart:html';

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

*Flutter version 1.17.4*
I am working on a Mac with *macOS 10.15.5* using an *Android Studio 4.0*

Android Studio 4.0
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 20, 2020

The coding was running smooth and got this error while debugging after I entered the following line of code.

```
signMeUp() {
    if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
      authMethods.signUpWithEmailAndPassword(
          emailTextEditingController.text, passwordTextEditingController.text);
    }
```

and the current error is given below, I seek help from anyone out there, this is my first flutter and I am its not going well.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Lenovo TB3 850M in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Compiler message:
lib/views/signUp.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/top_level.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.2/lib/js.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
export 'dart:js' show allowInterop, allowInteropCaptureThis;
^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.2/lib/js_util.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js_util'
export 'dart:js_util';
^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart:306:25: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var nextWrapper = allowInterop((firebase_interop.UserJsImpl user) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart:310:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => _changeController.addError(e));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart:340:25: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var nextWrapper = allowInterop((firebase_interop.UserJsImpl user) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart:345:11: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
          allowInterop((e) => _idTokenChangedController.addError(e));
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart:164:9: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DatabaseReference<T>'.
 - 'DatabaseReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
        allowInterop((update) => jsify(transactionUpdate(dartify(update))));
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart:166:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DatabaseReference<T>'.
 - 'DatabaseReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var onCompleteWrap = allowInterop(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart:301:24: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var callbackWrap = allowInterop((database_interop.DataSnapshotJsImpl data,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart:325:30: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    jsObject.once(eventType, allowInterop(
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:567:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:760:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:539:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compile (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:40:22)
#5      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:178:27)
#6      main (file:///b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:8:30)
#7      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/MAVERICK/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 882

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/MAVERICK/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 38s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: is mistaken 'dart:html' is imported in your file imports?

Comment: Are you building a website?  If not, dart:html provides a warning on import : info: Avoid using web-only libraries outside Flutter web plugin packages. (avoid_web_libraries_in_flutter at [meds] lib/core/helpers/med_request.dart:3)